# Is there a name for this kind of functions? $f(0)>0$ exists and $\dot{f}(t) \leqslant 0$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}{f}(t)=0$

Tags: limits

For this kind of functions $f$, the following properties of it are listed as:

1. $f(0)>0$ exists.
2. $\dot{f}(t) \leqslant 0$ for all $t \geqslant 0$.
3. $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} {f}(t)=0$.

Question: Is there a name for this kind of functions? Thank you very much.

Comment: *Why* do you think there is a name?

Comment: Maybe "a positive decreasing derivable function with limit $0$ at infinity" ?

Comment: Thank you @InfiniteLooper. I give up to find a normal name, and just describe the properties of it in my homwwork. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a natural curiosity, hhh. @Infinitesmal